hugo posts publishing inconsistently
i set up a hugo site, and used a theme, and made some sample posts.
however, the posts seem to be publishing inconsistently. that is, sometimes the posts will not publish (eg if i run "hugo", "hugo server", or "hugo server -D", and the appropriate files will not appear in the public folder. i can sometimes get things to publish and/or show up if i touch a file or make a change, but it's also not consistent.
also, it seems like sometimes even when the files themselves have been published, they will not show up in the list of posts on my home page. this also seems to be inconsistent, but less so.
i assume the second issue might be an issue with me modifying the theme incorrectly, but i'm not sure -- and i'm not sure where to start with the first.
my code can be found here: https://github.com/e-lu6a/hugo-starter/
i've tried checking that my posts are set to draft = false, tried building drafts, tried --noHTTPCache, tried --disableFastRender. i've tried deleting the files in the public folder, and rebuilding.
i expect that posts are consistently published and listed, on every rebuild.
what happens is posts often disappear, either from the post list -- or if i've deleted the published files and republished, will not get published at all.

for example, i have the following posts:
posts
  - sample-post.md
  - sample-post copy.md
architecture
  - sample-arch-post-copy.md
  - sample arch post.md

upon publishing, i neither the "posts" folder, nor the "architecture" folder appear in the public files.
i re-save all four .md files; they all appear and get published in the public folder, but only sample-post.md and sample-post copy.md appear on the home page.
i then re-save the menu.toml file, making no changes. this seems re-alert hugo, and the remaining two posts appear on the home page.
this is just one instance - there have also been cases where the posts will just no be published, or even if they are published, they just will not show up in on the home page in the menus.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
